# Run java jar file on a server as background process

Tags: shell, unix, executable-jar

I need to run a java jar in server in order to communicate between two applications. I have written two shell scripts to run it, but once I start up that script I can't shut down / terminate the process. If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or close the console, the server will shut down. Could anyone help me how to modify this script to run as a normal server?

```
 #!/bin/sh
java -jar /web/server.jar
echo $! 
#> startupApp.pid
```

Answer (score 319, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup java -jar /web/server.jar &
```

The & symbol, switches the program to run in the background.

The nohup utility makes the command passed as an argument run in the background even after you log out.

Comment: Thanks Anton,currntly im stopping the server by killing the process id.i don't think it's best practice.is thery command to to stop the server?

Comment: Short answer: it depends on the server. Long answer: as far as I know, there is no safe way to shut down a process without the process supporting such graceful shut downs. For example, if it's a web server being terminated by an external signal, there is always a possibility that some requests will be lost. One way to solve this problem is to implement a graceful termination function in the server itself, e.g. by processing a special kind of requests. Then, the server can be terminated by sending it a request of that special kind. Otherwise, killing the process by its ID is the simple way.

Comment: Using `nohup` should always be combined with redirecting stdout and stderr explicitly -- otherwise, you don't get control of where the logs go, and end up with an ugly `nohup.out` created in whichever directory this script happens to be invoked from.

Comment: @Anton 
when I run a script(just like your answer) with SSH EXEC runjar.sh. It started streaming the logs in my local terminal and if close my terminal my jar gets killed.
How can I run a jar in the background using SSH EXEC?

Answer (score 75):

**Systemd** which now runs in the majority of distros

## Step 1:

Find your user defined services mine was at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`

## Step 2:

Create a text file with your favorite text editor name it `whatever_you_want.service`

## Step 3:

Put following 
**Template** to the file `whatever_you_want.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=webserver Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /web/server.jar
User=user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## Step 4:

**Run your service**
*as super user*

```
$ systemctl start whatever_you_want.service # starts the service
$ systemctl enable whatever_you_want.service # auto starts the service
$ systemctl disable whatever_you_want.service # stops autostart
$ systemctl stop whatever_you_want.service # stops the service
$ systemctl restart whatever_you_want.service # restarts the service
```

Comment: This is the modern way of doing it

Comment: on aws ubutnu image I had to install systemd then found the image in /etc/systemd/system/

Comment: Where could I find the logs with this method?

Comment: If you have created the file, but face issue like "Failed to start ---- service", then run `systemctl daemon-reload` before Step 4. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364782/what-does-systemctl-daemon-reload-do

Answer (score 34):

If you're using Ubuntu and have "Upstart" (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) you can try this:

Create `/var/init/yourservice.conf`

with the following content

```
description "Your Java Service"  
author "You"  

start on runlevel [3]  
stop on shutdown  

expect fork  

script     
    cd /web 
    java -jar server.jar >/var/log/yourservice.log 2>&1  
    emit yourservice_running  
end script
```

Now you can issue the `service yourservice start` and `service yourservice stop` commands. You can tail `/var/log/yourservice.log` to verify that it's working.

If you just want to run your jar from the console without it hogging the console window, you can just do:

```
java -jar /web/server.jar > /var/log/yourservice.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Is that a systemd service? This question is not tagged linux, and very few distros have systemd by default.

Comment: I will amend the question to say that this is using "upstart" which is included in ubuntu.

Comment: I believe for the last advice if you want it to run in the background and the shell got released, you should do:

`java -jar /web/server.jar > /var/log/yourservice.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: All system jobs by default live in the following directory: /etc/init/ ... By default, there is no /var/init/ directory in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Also, starting a service requires "sudo". sudo service yourservice start

Answer (score 22):

Run in background and add logs to log file using the following:

```
nohup java -jar /web/server.jar > log.log 2>&1 &
```