# Run Maven project on web server in the background

Tags: java, linux, maven, webserver

### Problem

I have got a working Maven project that I would like to deploy on my web server. I have just discovered Maven and Java is not exactly the primary language I write my projects in, so please excuse any mistakes. When I run my project, a continuous HTTP connection is established and it should permanently run on the server (Basically Push Notifications based on made requests).

### Further Information

The server is running on Amazon's Linux AMI.

### Proposed Solution

I pack the whole Maven project into a `.jar` file and run it there.

**Q1** How do I run the java file on a server (in the background) ?

### Monitoring

**Q2** How can I monitor which or how many processes are working in the background ? (I would **NOT** want the java file to run multiple times, thus **PREVENTING** it from establishing multiple connections)

### Termination

**Q3** How would I terminate any background processes, if needed (terminate the continuous http connection)?

### Connected Questions

[Run java jar file on a server as background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102270/run-java-jar-file-on-a-server-as-background-process)

## EDIT

Possibly what I was looking for (I'll test it out and report back): https://serverfault.com/questions/152378/run-jar-in-background-on-linux

Comment: What everything is a subject to get processes up to date. It will never end if the cron is scheduled them to work.

Comment: @nikpon I am sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say... Can you rephrase that ?