# How to run a .jar file at boot within Screen (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: java, ubuntu

At boot, our server needs to start Teamspeak and a teamspeak bot. The first part works, teamspeak always starts, never an issue.
However, the teamspeak bot never starts, nor is the Screen session created.

rc.local file displayed below.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 2
su teamspeak -c 'screen -d -m -S ts3 /home/teamspeak/teamspeak/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh inifile=ts3server.ini'
sleep 2
su teamspeak -c 'screen -d -m -S tsbot /usr/bin/java -jar /home/teamspeak/jts3servermod/JTS3ServerMod.jar'
exit 0
```

As stated, teamspeak starts the way it should, within it's own screen session. The .jar file does not however and the screen session isn't there either.

Can someone tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: screen will exit if the command exits. Have you tried to run that java command from a shell interactively?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't run scripts like that. I'm not sure what's wrong but I would definitely write an sysv/upstart script to do that. [the second answer is what you should use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102270/run-java-jar-file-on-a-server-as-background-process)