# How to Deploy spring boot application on digital server cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I have created a spring boot application which i want to deploy with digital ocean servers, please can anyone guide me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run java application in the cloud using Digital Ocean:

**First**, [create](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven) executable jar/war file.

**Second**, [move](https://superuser.com/a/587673) generated file (jar/war) file to remote server (droplet).

**Third**, make sure the right version of java is installed (`which java`). If not [install](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml) it.

**Fourth**, [run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12102270/6252399) your jar as a detached process.

The better way is to package your application inside of docker container and deploy it in the orchestrated environment.

Comment: Thanks Alan for your help.. Do you know that the vps plans that digital ocean is providing does it contains database also in thier cpanel or do we need to install there. And if we installed our own database does it will create performance issue if we deploy our application.

Comment: I recommend using a managed solution instead of deploying and maintaining the database yourself. It is very easy to set up, try it out, dont take my word for it.

Comment: DigitalOcean provides database solutions, such as maintenance services like automates backups and such. Amazon (AWS) has RDS solution, which is basically the same thing, but from a different provider. The managed solution basically means that they take care of maintenance and hardware failure. It varies from provider to provider, but the main thing is that they all provide maintenance solutions.